# Android RecyclerView: why is Adapter's context returning warning?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have an [`Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html) file for a [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) that gives this Android Studio warning:
`Private field 'context' is assigned but never accessed` even though I use `this.context = context`.  I have another working app with an `Adapter` file that has the exact same code for the `context` and Android Studio does not give a warning for that file.  What am I missing here?

`ContactListAdapter.java` file with warning:

```
package com.example.jdw.sixteenthversion;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ListViewHolder> {

private List<Contact> contactList;
**private Context context**;

private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

This is the working app's `ContactListAdapter.java` file and no Studio warning:

```
package com.wimso.android_sqlite.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wimso.android_sqlite.R;
import com.wimso.android_sqlite.listener.RecyclerItemClickListener;
import com.wimso.android_sqlite.model.Contact;
import com.wimso.android_sqlite.widget.LetterTile;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ContactListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactListAdapter.ContactHolder>{

private List<Contact> contactList;
**private Context context**;

private RecyclerItemClickListener recyclerItemClickListener;

public ContactListAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.contactList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Are you using context in any other place other than this.context = context?  If not that is the reason why you are getting the warning.

Comment: No other places.  Why would I get the warning in one app's file but I don't get the warning in the other app's file that has the exact same "this.context=context" code.

Comment: That is the reason why you are getting the warning.

Comment: Please recheck again.

Comment: I have both app's open in Android Studio.  And I only get an error message in the one.

Answer (score 0):

This warning means, you dont use your `context` field in rest of class. If you dont need it you can delete it. Unless you dont delete it gonna be not a problem.

Comment: I use it in the "public ContactListAdapter(Context context)" method.  If I delete "private Context context" then app will crash.

Comment: This context is another context as a parameter comes from where you call ContactListAdapter. Also delete from constructor if you dont need context rest of ContactListAdapter class.